# Using HTML Button to Call JavaScript Function with Parameters

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, base64

I am trying to call a JavaScript function with parameters via HTML button.

HTML:

```
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="callFunc("<?php $x='Hello World'; echo $x; ?>")" />
```

JavaScript:

```
/*

* Convert string to a base-64 string

*/

function str2b64(input) {

  try { b64pad } catch(e) { b64pad=''; }

    var tab = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
    var output = "";
    var len = input.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i += 3) {
        var triplet = (input.charCodeAt(i) << 16)
                | (i + 1 < len ? input.charCodeAt(i+1) << 8 : 0)
                | (i + 2 < len ? input.charCodeAt(i+2)      : 0);
        for(var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if(i * 8 + j * 6 > input.length * 8) output += b64pad;
            else output += tab.charAt((triplet >>> 6*(3-j)) & 0x3F);
        }
    }
  alert(output);

}
```

What I get at run time or on click is absolutely NOTHING! As soon as I remove the variable I am passing it works as intended.

Not sure why I am having issues but regardless any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What is `$param`, is it a defined variable in global scope? if not its going to throw an error and halt the rest of the script, which you should see in the javascript console

Comment: So.. you call the function "callFunc" but it dosn't exist...

Comment: @Patrick Evans $param is actually a PHP variable of type string. I call the callFunc() passing it a variable $x='some string'; to be converted into a base-64 string. No actual errors that display just does nothing. $param is not global. The value of $x is what ever a user enters into a form textbox.

Comment: `onclick=str2b64(<?php ... ?>)`

Comment: Thank you Stack Overflow Community! The problem was fixed by using single quotes ' and NOT double quotes " e.g. onclick="callFunc('<?php echo $x; ?>')"  Feeling dumb as I thought I tried both single and double quotes. Sorry!